# Start-Job - Positional order of arguments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand the correct order of arguments when using `Start-Job`. What is the correct way to supply parameters to a PowerShell job?

I would expect this to print `hello world`, but it prints `world hello`.

Is `Param()` or `-ArgumentList` the issue here?

```
$foo = "hello"
$bar = "world"

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Param(
        $foo,
        $bar
    )
    Write-Host $foo
    Write-Host $bar
} -ArgumentList $bar, $foo

Receive-Job $job
```

Output:

```
world
hello
```

Comment: `$foo` inside your job will allways be the first object given in the `-ArgumentList`. In this case `$bar`. The object allocation will be dependent on the position, not on the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of the parameter `-ArgumentList` is an array, whose values are passed to parameters defined inside the scriptblock in positional order. You're confused about the result you're getting, because you apparently expected your global variables to be mapped to the parameter names you defined in your scriptblock. That is not how this works.

To maybe illustrate a bit better what is happening in your example let's use distinct variable names in the scriptblock and global scope:

```
$a = "hello"
$b = "world"

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Param(
        $c,
        $d
    )
    Write-Host $c
    Write-Host $d
} -ArgumentList $b, $a
```

Essentially, the names of the parameters have nothing to do with the names of the variables in the global scope.

You're switching the values when you're passing `$b, $a` to the scriptblock instead of `$a, $b`, hence the value of `$b` is passed to `$c` and the value of `$a` is passed to `$d`.

Normally one would use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) for mapping values to specific named parameters. However, that won't work here, since `-ArgumentList` expects an array of values, not a hashtable. If the difference between positional and named parameters is not clear to you please have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0).

What you can do if you want to use the same variable names inside and outside the scriptblock is use the `using:` scope qualifier instead of passing the variables as arguments:

```
$a = "hello"
$b = "world"

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host $using:a
    Write-Host $using:b
}
```

Comment: I was just writing up a very similar answer to this, no need now as yours covers all the points I also had. I would only add that it might help OP to read [about_functions_advanced_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) as this covers named and positional parameters.

Comment: @JamesC. The problem the OP is facing is not how parameters (named or unnamed) work in general, but that `-ArgumentList` simply does not allow passing named parameters. Hence I don't think the parameters documentation is particularly helpful here.

Comment: I wasn't saying that specifically was the issue, you reference both types of parameters, and I'm not sure if OP understands about how the behaviour they are currently seeing is the args they are passing being used with positional params.

Comment: I thought that was what my answer explained? ;) Anyway, documentation link added.